# AngularJS: $http.post multiple values using textarea?

Tags: html, angularjs, textarea

I've got an app, which posts value from user entered text to sql server table using web api, sql table values then displayed in the html page. I would like to use textarea to save multiple values so far it does this (concatenates them into one replacing line break with space):

[image: html]

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.saveSubs = function () {
        var sub = {
         //  DisplayName: $scope.DisplayName


        };
        var saveSubs = APIService.saveSubscriber(sub);
        saveSubs.then(function (d) {
            getAll();
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.');
        });
    };
```

**Post Service:**

```
app.service("APIService", function ($http) {
    this.getSubs = function () {
        var url = 'api/Subscriber';
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });        
    }
    this.saveSubscriber = function (sub) {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            data: sub,
            url: 'api/Subscriber'
        });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="txtDescEd" cols="60" rows="10" data-ng-model="mailid"></textarea>
        </div>



        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="saveSubs();">Submit</button>
        <p id='target' style='white-space:pre'>
```

Comment: What is the expectation? Do you want to make multiple web service calls (one for each row)? Or do you want to make one web service call with the input as an array?

Comment: Either way would work

Answer (score 0):

Ideal solution would be to make one web service call and save multiple subscribers together.

Use the `.split` function to split the input text like below.

```
this.saveSubscriber = function (sub) {
    return $http({
        method: 'post',
        data: sub.split('\n'),
        url: 'api/Subscriber'
    });
```

Note: For this to work, the web service has to support array of strings as input.